# How to install Chart.js without a library?

Tags: chart.js

How can I install **Chart.js** "manually"?

Chart.js documentation mentions **gulp** and **npm** and **bower**, all Greek to me. I've read about each of them but am not interested in installing other libraries, I just want to draw charts. It appears that bower was not an option for a while and [someone on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761473/why-is-node-js-required-to-develop-and-install-chart-js) claimed Node.js is not required for Chart.js but gave no details of how to install it bare.

I DLed it, unzipped it, put it on my server, and get a "ReferenceError: Chart is not defined" when I try to use it and see that the code references a 'dist' directory that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use the CDN

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js/1.0.2

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed it did!!