# How do I install Chart.js as a file?

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to replace Flot.js with Chart.js.  In my application, Flot.js is included as a normal JavaScript file, like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot-0.8.3.js"></script>
```

I'm looking for a way to do the same for Chart.js.

The [releases](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v4.4.0) section of the Chart.js GitHub page has packages available for download.  From its v4.4.0 `.tgz` package, for example, I found the `package/dist/chart.js` file and included it in my application.  After doing so, the console reports the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module chart.js:7:1

(In fact, the very first non-comment line of `chart.js` is an import statement:

```
/*!
 * Chart.js v4.4.0
 * https://www.chartjs.org
 * (c) 2023 Chart.js Contributors
 * Released under the MIT License
 */
import { r as requestAnimFrame, a as resolve, e as effects, c as color, i as isObject, d as defaults, b as isArray, v as valueOrDefault, u as unlistenArrayEvents, l as listenArrayEvents, f as resolveObjectKey, ...
```

so I'm not certain what to make of this error.  Is `chart.js` not the top level of the `chart.js` module?  If not, what is?)

In addition, when I insert the "Hello world" example given in the Chart.js [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/), no chart is created on the page and the console additionally reports the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

I found similar files available via a [CDN page](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js).  These files appear to be equivalent in content to the package files from the Chart.js GitHub, and when I include them in my application I get the same result.

I have found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43959072/6673905), where the only useful answer doesn't provide any more detail than what I've already tried, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41191713/6673905), where the only answer is to use the CDN, which is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to incorporate Chart.js as a first-party file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the UMD build of chart.js then it will work fine: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.js`

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you.